# Auto allocation while scanning string in C

Tags: c

I am aware that asprintf writes to a string, which it also auto allocates. Also, that STDIN is the input buffer. Incorporating these two specific facts, I want to write a function that accepts a string and automatically allocates the storage space. I am also aware of the alternative way of doing it manually. I am just curious if this can be an alternative way.

Here is my approach,

```
int main()
{

    char *str;
    int i;
    __fpurge(stdin);               //To clear contents of stdin
    asprintf(&str,"%10s",stdin);   //To take only 10 characters
    if(str)
    {   printf("Read %d characters -> %s",i,str);
        free(str);
    }

 }
```

However, I am getting something like this ->

Read 11 characters -> //followed by some gibberish

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `scanf("%10ms%n", &str, &i);` or `getline`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is invalid. `stdin` is of type `FILE *`, whereas `asprintf` is expecting a `char *` (since the conversion specifier is `%s`).

If you want to read from `stdin`, you need to use a function that's designed to read from a
 `FILE *`, e.g. `fgets` or `fscanf`.

Comment: I understand the flaw. Is there a way whereby I can use asprintf to read strings from stdin?

Comment: Nope, `asprintf` and the other members of the `printf` family have no mechanism for reading from a file.